# Refreshing the GeoCache and Boundaries in OpenGeo suite

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite, geowebcache, geoexplorer

Currently if I add a new site i can query the layer and see where the point should be however it does not always display in Geoexplorer or OpenLayers preview. However sometimes it does show in Openlayers but not Geoexplorer. I think this is down to the GeoCache, and the Bounding Box around the data. I clear my internet history each time too.

Edit:

I have tried deleting the Geoserver cache, reseeding the layer at zoom levels 0-15. The odd thing is at zoom level 2, all points appear and then when I zoom in a progressively loose points on the map. However the data is still visible, if I query the layer?

Any suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change two things in geoserver:
open your layer to edit, on the first tab (data) change the bounding box manually to a much bigger area.
Go to the fourth tab (tile chasing)  and turn off the "Create a cached layer for this layer" box. Save it, and check it in geoexplorer.

Tamas